# How to set up Amazon DynamoDB Client on AWS (JAVA)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to set up a client for my  Amazon DynamoDB in Java 8 and am running into this error when I try to run my lambda function locally. I am trying to connect to  Amazon DynamoDB and I already have set up in AWS Management Console.

> Error trying to commit audit record:com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSignatureException;

I am still new to AWS and trying to understand how it works. I am sure the credentials I provided matched the ones I have.

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClient.builder()
            .withRegion("us-east-2")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new 
             BasicAWSCredentials("key","private key")))
            .build();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("tableName")
```

Comment: Can you validate the date time on your host machine is accurate?

Comment: I believe it is. I never changed my time and it is the same as US-East-2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try out changing according to example in AWS docs, without explicitly setting credential provider.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for creating a table and this is working:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id");

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .build();

        //        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
//            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-west-2"))
//            .build();

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

        String tableName = "Songs";

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to create table; please wait...");

            Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(tableName,
                Arrays.asList(

                    new KeySchemaElement("year", KeyType.HASH), // Partition
                    // key
                    new KeySchemaElement("title", KeyType.RANGE)), // Sort key
                Arrays.asList(new AttributeDefinition("year", ScalarAttributeType.N),
                    new AttributeDefinition("title", ScalarAttributeType.S)),
                new ProvisionedThroughput(10L, 10L));

            table.waitForActive();
            System.out.println("Success.  Table status: " + table.getDescription().getTableStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to create table: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```